# Saving a picture from picturebox to database with bindingsource c#

Tags: c#, sql, bindingsource

Sorry if the answer is going to be obvious.

I'm busy with a winforms app in c# with a sqlcompact DB. I'm using a dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter, adapter manager, binding navigator.

I have been struggling for a day now to save a picture from a picture box to the database and keep getting "@p18 : janeman - Input string was not in a correct format."

I've tried to add the binding manual as well :

`pbOneGeneralEmployees.DataBindings.Add("Image", employeeDataBindingSource, "IDPhoto", true);`

But no luck...

How would I go about saving / viewing the image?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did see [this post, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451591/image-databinding-to-the-picturebox) Maybe you need `yourTableName.IDPhoto` ?

Comment: I just got it, I deleted the table from the DataSet, deleted the column IDPhoto from the table schema, closed VS, open VS, added the the column, added the table back to the DataSet, and it just worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it,

I deleted the table from the DataSet, 
deleted the column IDPhoto from the table schema, 
closed VS, 
open VS, 
added the the column, 
added the table back to the DataSet,

**and it just worked**